# Where is sys/types.h located?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

I just found out that the `<stdlib.h>` and `<stdio.h>` headers are located in the `/usr/include` folder in Ubuntu server, but I don't find `sys/types.h`.

And I start to suspect the compiler won't actually use the header file in the `/usr/include` folder.

Is this true, and where is the file located?

Comment: No, header files must be present. Maybe look in /usr/local/include.

Comment: `echo "#include <sys/types.h>" | gcc -E -x c - | grep types` to see where it is picking it up from

Comment: @Mat It works, I find it out, BTW what's the last parameter `-` used for?

Comment: Perhaps this should be asked at [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) or [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/)?

Comment: @PauloScardine you are right, how can I move this question?

Comment: @yozloy: `-` stands for "read from stdin rather than a file".

Comment: @JonathanLeffler interesting! So the compile does not actually read the header file locate in some path?

Comment: Actually, since gcc is very much one of the "software tools commonly used by programmers", you could go either way, here or AskUbuntu. I'd be indifferent leaving it here since it's actually useful outside of the Ubuntu arena as well (but I'll defer to the swarm).

Comment: @H2CO3: actually, header files do not have to be present under `/usr/include`.  You might like to look for `<stdarg.h>`; it does not exist on my Linux or Mac OS X machines — somewhat to my considerable surprise, I might add!  (More precisely, it is not found in `/usr/include` or its sub-directories.  For my Mac OS X install of GCC 4.7.1 (home-built) where the base directory is `/usr/gcc/v4.7.1`, the header exists at `/usr/gcc/v4.7.1/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0/4.7.1/include/stdarg.h`.)

Comment: Actually, @JonathanLeffler is quite right. The manner in which header files are located is _totally_ implementation defined so they don't have to exist physically on a file system _at all._ It's quite possible that a compiler just inject state based on what you include. It may even reach out to the FSF web site to get the header, though it'd be annoying to lose the ability to compile if the network connection was down :-)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler so it's present :)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

My Debian box (and hopefully Ubuntu haven't butchered it *too* much in their zeal) has it in `/usr/include/sys/types.h`.

Your best bet is to execute:

```
find /usr/include -name types.h
find / -name types.h # if not found by one above
```

However, keep in mind that the development stuff may not even be *installed* on a server. Unless it's a server for a compiler farm, it wouldn't surprise me if the compiler and a bunch of other stuff was not part of the default install.

If the compiler *is* locating it somewhere and you just don't know where, you can use something like:

```
echo "#include <sys/types.h>" | gcc -E -x c - | grep /types.h
```

to find out where it's getting it from.

That `gcc` command line:

- stops after the pre-processing phase (`-E`);
- forces the file to be treated as C source code (`-x c`); and
- retrieves the program from standard input (`-`), in this case from the `echo` statement.

The final `grep` just strips out the unimportant lines leaving the ones that are likely to contain the location of the included file.

Comment: Wow, what's an answer, I've learned so much, and the `gcc` way works, now I found the file

Comment: @yozloy, just out of interest, where was it?

Comment: On Ubuntu 12, I found this at `/usr/include/linux/types.h`.

Answer (score 16):

The file `sys/types.h` is located at the `/usr/include/sys/types.h`

if u get this kind of **Fatal Error**:

```
.../linux/linux_types.h:146:38: fatal error: /usr/include/sys/types.h: No
such file or directory
```

**Fix** by using the following code:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential flex libelf-dev libc6-dev-amd64 binutils-dev libdwarf-dev
```

Comment: if it's just for sys/types.h I *think* build-essential should do the trick.

Comment: On linux mint 16: sudo apt-get install build-essential was enough.

Answer (score 10):

If you have locate command available you can simply use `locate`:

```
-bash-3.2$ locate sys/types.h
/usr/include/sys/types.h
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/sys/types.h
-bash-3.2$
```

It's the quickest and simplest way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Just for future reference, I ran into this problem on my debian machine, and it turned out that in my case

```
$ apt-file find /usr/include/sys/types.h
libc6-dev-i386: /usr/include/sys/types.h
```

libc6-dev-i386 is the package I seemingly need to install

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, `types.h` should be in `/usr/include/sys/types.h`.