# fatal error: 'bits/types.h' file not found

Tags: c, compilation

When I try to compile a C program on MAC I get the following error message:

> /usr/local/include/stdio.h:35:11: fatal error: 'bits/types.h' file not found

```
#include <bits/types.h>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I have played around with these files before.

Would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11823339/1795279) answer.

To Fix the error do the following.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential flex libelf-dev libc6-dev-amd64 binutils-dev libdwarf-dev
```

Comment: I'm using a mac - this does not work with brew. I get this error message:    Error: No available formula with the name "build-essential" 
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.

Comment: @MichaelFrazis then i suppose you have to install those libraries manually

Comment: I wiped my hard drive and reinstalled OS X - this is the only thing that worked, and I spent a lot of time on this. Will not be playing around with those files again!

Comment: They're on a Mac.

Comment: Use `libc6-dev` instead of `libc6-dev-amd64` for Ubuntu 20.04.